# US visa application for tourist - listed in F4 application Of father

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, family

In 2007, My wife's uncle filled F4 immigration for my father-in-law. At that time she was 18years old. Now she is married to me and living with me in Canada. She doesn't have US visa. Now we are planning to apply.

In application there is question that did you ever apply for US immigration. In this situation what should I do? Mark yes or no. Because she was not primary applicant, just listed as a daughter.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, disclose.  You will never get in trouble for including information about something you didn't need to include.

> In this situation what should I do? Mark yes or no.

Mark yes, and include as much information as you can.